# LINQ update de todos os itens listados (alterando o status de todos os itens listados)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Tenho um Linq que apresenta dados listados de acordo com os filtros requeridos (data e unidade) pelo usuário e outro filtro para validar um código com outra tabela(que não vêm ao caso). Gostaria de saber como eu posso a partir de um botão "conciliar", alterar o status (NFBP_STA_LANCTO) de todos os itens listados nesta tabela.

```
            int _idUnidade = int.Parse(cboUnidade.SelectedValue);
            DateTime _dtCred = DateTime.Parse(txtCred.Text, new CultureInfo("pt-br"));

            using (NFSeDataContext context = new NFSeDataContext(ConnNFSe))
            {
                context.Connection.Open();

                var _s = (from p in context.NFS_Parcelas
                          join q in context.NFBP_CONCILIACAO_BRASPAGs on p.NFPA_NR_PARCELA equals q.NFBP_NR_PARCELA
                          where
                            _idUnidade == p.NFPA_CD_UNIDADE
                           && _dtCred == p.NFPA_DT_MOVIMENTO
                           && SqlMethods.Like(p.NFPA_TX_COMPLEMENTO, "%" + q.NFBP_TID + "%")
                          orderby p.NFPA_NR_PARCELA
                          select new
                          {
                              q.NFBP_STA_LANCTO,
                              p.NFPA_CD_UNIDADE,
                              p.NFPA_DT_MOVIMENTO,
                              q.NFBP_COD_AUTORIZACAO,
                              q.NFBP_TID,
                              q.NFBP_VL_BRUTO_TRANSACAO,
                              q.NFBP_VL_LIQUIDO_TRANSACAO,
                              p.NFPA_NR_PARCELA,
                              q.NFBP_BANDEIRA
                          }).ToList();

                context.Connection.Close();
                grvConciliacaoBraspag.DataSource = _s;
                grvConciliacaoBraspag.DataBind();
```

Imagem pra tornar o mais claro possível o que está sendo feito(front-end):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É Entity Framework?

Comment: Sim @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Qual a chave de `Parcelas`?

Comment: PK_NFS_PARCELA @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, não use estes dois comandos:

```
context.Connection.Open();
context.Connection.Close();
```

O Entity Framework fecha a conexão quando necessário. Você não precisa fazer isso manualmente.

Essa sua seleção é boa pra grid, mas não pro resto, então faça o seguinte:

```
var _s = (from p in context.NFS_Parcelas
                      join q in context.NFBP_CONCILIACAO_BRASPAGs on p.NFPA_NR_PARCELA equals q.NFBP_NR_PARCELA
                      where
                        _idUnidade == p.NFPA_CD_UNIDADE
                       && _dtCred == p.NFPA_DT_MOVIMENTO
                       && SqlMethods.Like(p.NFPA_TX_COMPLEMENTO, "%" + q.NFBP_TID + "%")
                      orderby p.NFPA_NR_PARCELA
                      select new {
                          Parcela = p, ItemConciliacao = q
                      }).ToList();
```

Ao enviar pra Grid, você seleciona os campos que precisa:

```
var dsGrid = _s.Select(new { 
                          ItemConciliacao.NFBP_STA_LANCTO,
                          Parcela.NFPA_CD_UNIDADE,
                          Parcela.NFPA_DT_MOVIMENTO,
                          ItemConciliacao.NFBP_COD_AUTORIZACAO,
                          ItemConciliacao.NFBP_TID,
                          ItemConciliacao.NFBP_VL_BRUTO_TRANSACAO,
                          ItemConciliacao.NFBP_VL_LIQUIDO_TRANSACAO,
                          Parcela.NFPA_NR_PARCELA,
                          ItemConciliacao.NFBP_BANDEIRA
                      }).ToList();
```

Tendo `_s`, fica simples:

```
foreach (var parcela in _s.Select(s => s.Parcela).ToList())
{
    parcela.NFBP_STA_LANCTO = /* Coloque aqui o status novo */
    context.Entry(parcela).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para você alterar o valor de um registro de uma determinada entidade do EntityFramework, você precisar buscar o objeto que você quer alterar. Nesta lista "_s", não é possível alterar o valor de nada pois ela não é um objeto da entidade "NFBP_CONCILIACAO_BRASPAGs", "_s" é apenas uma lista de um novo objeto anonimo que você cria utilizando os dados das entidades que você seleciona via LINQ.

Você pode retornar neste seu objeto anonimo a chave necessária para buscar um registro da tabela "NFBP_CONCILIACAO_BRASPAGs". Deste modo você consegue selecionar o objeto exato para atualizar o valor.

Exemplo:

```
foreach (var record in _s) 
{
    var nfpb = context.NFBP_CONCILIACAO_BRASPAGs.Single(a => a.chave == record.chave && a.chave2 == record.chave2); // Se for chave composta, se for um id pode ignorar o &&
    nfpb.NFBP_STA_LANCTO = novo_valor;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Outra opção seria você retornar ao invés de um objeto anonimo com os valores, retornar um objeto anonimo com os objetos das entidades, porem esta solução vai impactar na visão que utiliza esta lista "_s". Então talvez você tenha que fazer uma consulta exatamente igual, porem alterando o que é selecionado.

```
            var _s = (from p in context.NFS_Parcelas
                      join q in context.NFBP_CONCILIACAO_BRASPAGs on p.NFPA_NR_PARCELA equals q.NFBP_NR_PARCELA
                      where
                        _idUnidade == p.NFPA_CD_UNIDADE
                       && _dtCred == p.NFPA_DT_MOVIMENTO
                       && SqlMethods.Like(p.NFPA_TX_COMPLEMENTO, "%" + q.NFBP_TID + "%")
                      orderby p.NFPA_NR_PARCELA
                      select new
                      {
                          Parcela = p,
                          Conciliacao = q
                      }).ToList();

foreach (var record in _s) 
{      
    record.Conciliacao.NFBP_STA_LANCTO = novo_valor;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```